# Why this code does not work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I can't understand why this code does not work in Firefox (it works in Safari, Chrome and IE). m1, n1, m2 and n2 are four text input

```
<button class="btn btn-warning"><a style="color:white;" class="btn" onclick="save()" > Calcola </a></button> ...

... <script type="text/javascript"> 
  function save(){
    var m1 = document.getElementById("m1").value;
    var n1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;

    var m2 = document.getElementById("m2").value;
    var n2 = document.getElementById("n2").value; 

    window.location = ("?clicco=true&m1="+m1+"&n1="+n1+"&m2="+m2+"&n2="+n2);

  }
</script>
```

Comment: 36.0.1 but I tried it also on other versions

Comment: *What* doesn't work?  Do you see anything in your console?  Does the event trigger, does the `save()` function run?  Are you getting the right values?  Do you go to the right page?

Comment: Maybe you need to do `window.location = window.location.href + '?...'` or something?

Comment: I can't see anything in my console and I go to the right page (the same code works in other browser). It seems like onclick does not work. the function is not called

Comment: `I go to the right page` - is this when you click the button?

Answer (score 0):

attaching the click event to the button may also be a good idea, since you aren't using the href attribute on the  tag to redirect..

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="save()"> Calcola </button>
```

Comment: Also this version works on all the browser except on Firefox

Comment: Solved! Thank you. I moved the onclick action on the button

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it doesn't work is that there are two actions that compete. The default action of the button is to submit the form, so if that is handled before the click event you won't see the effect of the function.

Binding the event on the button instead and returning `false` from the event handler will stop the default action of the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="return save()"><a style="color:white;" class="btn"> Calcola </a></button> ...

... <script type="text/javascript"> 
  function save(){
    var m1 = document.getElementById("m1").value;
    var n1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;

    var m2 = document.getElementById("m2").value;
    var n2 = document.getElementById("n2").value; 

    window.location = ("?clicco=true&m1="+m1+"&n1="+n1+"&m2="+m2+"&n2="+n2);

    return false;
  }
</script>
```